# Repeat a block dependent on an integer using Meteor/Blaze

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have an integer in my mongo collection to define a count, called 'tweet_count'. I need to repeat an icon based on this value, like so:

Helper:

```
Template.companyList.helpers({
    companies: function () {
        return Tweets.find();
    }
});
```

Blaze:

```
{{#each companies}}
    {{ LOOP BASED ON tweet_count}}
       <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
    {{ /LOOP }}
{{/each}}
```

A sample of the Mongo collection looks like:

```
{
"_id" : "xxx",
"name" : "xxx",
"handle" : "xxx",
"tweet_count" : 2,
"tweets" : [
    {
        "tweet_id" : "x",
        "text" : "x",
        "created_at" : "Tue Jul 04 15:56:33 +0000 2017",
        "retweet_count" : 0,
        "from" : "x",
        "from_full_name" : "x",
        "from_profile_image" : "x"
    },
    {
        "tweet_id" : "x",
        "text" : "x9",
        "created_at" : "Tue Jul 04 15:56:47 +0000 2017",
        "retweet_count" : 0,
        "from" : "x",
        "from_full_name" : "x",
        "from_profile_image" : "x"
    }
]
}
```

How can I achieve this using Meteor/Blaze? I have tried `each` but it only accepts an array which I do not have for this value, as it's simply a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a helper that returns an array with the size of tweet_count:

```js
Template.companyList.helpers({
    companies: function () {
        return Tweets.find();
    },
    getTweetCount(tweet_count) {
        const ret = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < tweet_count; i++) {
            ret.push(i);
        }
        return ret;
    }
});
```

It receives the tweet count and returns the empty array with size of tweet count. You call it from Blaze Syntax in the following way:

```html
<template name="companyList">
    {{#each companies}}
        <span>{{this.name}}</span>
        {{#each getTweetCount this.tweet_count}}
            <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

The `this` refers to the current document, so this.tweet_count is the number that gets passed to your helper function getTweetCount.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't output anything, although I can see what you're suggesting

Comment: If it's not outputting anything then `this.tweet_count` is probably undefined. Just make sure to pass the function the right value.

Comment: I thought tweet_count is part of the companies collection. To which collection is it related to?

Comment: Yes it's part of companies. {{#each companies}}{{tweet_count}}{{/each}} outputs my integer value.

Comment: tweet_count is in brackets, which indicates that it is calling a function from your helpers. Can you add it to the code of your question? I assumed it is the name of a field in the current companies doc.

Comment: No, it's not calling a function. It's in {{ }} as without that it would just output the literal words 'tweet_count'. 'tweet_count' is a field in the Mongo collection.

Comment: Then it should work by calling `{{ #each getTweetCount tweet_count}}` if not, you may post a little bit more of your template, because his is a common approach and should work fine. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Strange! I have updated the question with more detail.

Comment: Found the issue: the array needs to have values other than undefined. Works on my example project. Learned something new for myself ;-)

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! Glad we both got something out of it!